# Linux live boot flash drive works on PC but not Mac

Tags: linux, boot, windows, live-usb, macintosh

I've created a bootable Linux USB flash drive on my Windows 7 PC. 
I can use it on any PC (running Windows),
but I have been unable to boot it on my Apple Macbook Air.

How can I boot my Linux live boot on an Apple computer?

Comment: What happens when you try booting it on your Mac?

Comment: This question has to Kali nothing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key (<kbd>alt</kbd>) when the computer boots up with your flash drive containing the Live boot operating system connected. You should see a screen allowing you to choose between your Hard drive (Currently installed Operating Systems) and the flash drive. Select your flash drive and in a minute or so you should be booting into your Live boot operating system. That is how you boot off of a flash drive on an Apple computer.

## *If that does not work...*

You may need to set up your flash drive again.

Using the `terminal` in macOS run the following commands:

```
hdiutil convert /path/to/downloaded.iso -format UDRW -o /path/to/newimage
diskutil list //Here you will be verifying which device your flash drive i.e. /dev/disk3 or /dev/sdb
diskutil unmountDisk /dev/[NameofFlashDrive] 
sudo dd if=/path/to/newimage.dmg of=/dev/[NameofFlashDrive] bs=1m
```

This creates a bootable image that your Apple hardware can work with on your flash drive. Please take care to make sure you use the `dd` command on the correct device. After you have completed this power down your Apple computer, make sure the flash drive is connected, and follow the steps outlined in the beginning of this post.

[Source](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-boot-a-linux-live-usb-stick-on-your-mac/)

Please comment if you have any questions or issues with this answer. I highly suggest you read through the link I have provided thoroughly before attempting the commands. I appreciate feedback to correct any misconceptions and to improve my posts. I can update my answer as needed.

Best of Luck!